# CnosDB alter USER xxx SET COMMENT= 'vvv'; bug

Tags: cnosdb

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQYqU.png)
version：CnosDB:v2.2
command：cnosdb/target/debug/cnosdb-cli -P 8902 -H 127.0.0.1

```
 Hello everyone, today when I was following the CnosDB documentation to operate SQL statements, after creating the user, when I tried to modify the user data, there was no error and the data did not change at all. I have tested it multiple times but without success. Could you please help me take a look at this issue? Thank you.
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)